# DataTables warning: table id=trainingMaterialTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Tags: javascript, jquery

DataTables warning: table id=trainingMaterialTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3 how to solve this error.

Comment: Kindly share your JS code to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Don't call twice in a page

For Example :
index.html - In javascript section :

**Avoid :**

```
<script>
         $('#example').dataTable( {
            paging: false
        } );

     $('#example').dataTable( {
            paging: false
        } );
</script>
```

**Use :**

```
 <script>
             $('#example').dataTable( {
                paging: false
            } );


    </script>
```